# Passing Parameters to Tableau Report

Tags: uri, tableau-api

I am working with a few Tableau reports and have been tasked to provide URL's from our CRM to specific reports based on a user. The filter option on the report has a list of all the names of the people that can be selected.

Normally, I just find out what the field name is in the post data and then add that to the URL and pass a value. I am running into an issue with this specific field though, and I don't know if it is due to the contents of the field name or the value.

Field: `[federated.1ul6fri07nr5aw1a3nzo40270755].[Action (Employee and EmpId)]`

Value: `Jim Smith (123456789)`

I am trying to add a parameter to filter to this specific person like so:

Attempt: `https://domain/#/site/Business/views/WeeklyClockin_0/Data?State=California&Action (Employee and EmpId)=Jim Smith (123456789)`

I have also tried replacing the spaces with `%20`, but that didn't work either. If I leave the field off, and only filter by `State`, it is working fine.

I am not sure if it is the parenthesis in the field name / field value that is throwing it off , or something else with my attempt.

Is there anything special that needs to be done with field names like this where it is not a simple 1-word field name (such as `&State=xxx`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Calculated Field that builds the Employee + ID format that you want. Then, use said Calculated Field on the URL.